# SQL Error: Incorrect Syntax near the keyword User

Tags: sql, keyword

I am trying to write my first SQL query against a database to pull a list of users. I am using Crystal Reports, and when I go thru the report builder and then run it I get the above error.

When I look at the SQL Query I see this:

```
SELECT
    User."Disabled", User."UserName"
FROM
    "Database"."dbo"."User" User           
ORDER BY
    User."UserName" ASC
```

I saw other articles saying user needs to be in Brackets so I did this:

```
SELECT
    User."Disabled", User."UserName"
FROM
    "Database"."dbo"."User" [User]           
ORDER BY
    User."UserName" ASC
```

When I do that I then get an error message that says:

> Cannot call methods on nvarchar

Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Harold Roberts, maybe if you change all User by [User], Based on this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853631/error-occured-cannot-call-methods-on-nvarchar, user is a reserved word

Comment: This is what I wound up doing and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using double quotes at all?  I would start with:

```
SELECT u.Disabled, u.UserName
FROM Database.dbo.User u           
ORDER BY u.UserName ASC
```

You don't specify your database, but words like `User` are often reserved words, so they make a poor choice for an identifier name.

Comment: I agree but this is an OLD database written by another company that I am just trying to pull some data from.  The database table is called User and the the field I want is called username.  The only part I changed is the word database

Comment: OK so this seems to at least pull all of the data I am looking for.  I had to actually put [] around every word user in the entire system

Answer (score 0):

Like it was suggest in error message: User is keyword. You can replace `User` alias you are using with simple `u`. Like:

```
SELECT u."Disabled", u."UserName"
  FROM "Database"."dbo"."User" u           
 ORDER BY u."UserName" ASC
```

Comment: I did not think I could change that in the select command. I will give this a try and see what happens.